# can we create business rules that span across different table in dataverse

Tags: dataverse, power-platform

I have a one to many relationship from Student table and Class table, the lookup column in Class table is Student ID in Students Table. Class table has a  column which is "Stutas", if all the records in Stauts in class table are "finished", I want  the Student table's column "StudyStatus" to be "Completed", otherwise "Uncompleted". how to do it in Dataverse？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with business rules.

I see 3 options:

1. Plugin registered on table Student
2. Classic workflow
3. Power Automate flow

A plugin is technically the ideal solution: status on Student can be kept in sync within a transaction and processing requires minimal processing. However, you would need to develop code.

A classic workflow can also run in transaction (when it is executed synchronously), but making things work here still requires custom code.

With a Power Automate flow you can build your solution without programming. However, a PA flow is executed asynchronously.

> Keep in mind that you may need to address not only the update trigger, but also the create and delete triggers.